# Postgres Range Fields + Rails Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Are there any standard ways of integrating the [Postgres range types](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#range-types) with the Rails form helpers? I basically need a min and max field that get converted into a range on saving. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

At first I was thinking about something like this:

```
class Model
  delegate :begin, :end, to: :range, prefix: true, allow_nil: true # Replace :range with your field name
end
```

To get methods: `range_begin`, `range_end`. I checked documentation and these methods are read only.

So you need also setters:

```
class Model
  delegate :begin, :end, to: :range, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  def range_begin=(value)
    self.range = Range.new(value, (range_end || value))
  end

  def range_end=(value)
    self.range = Range.new((range_begin || value), value)
  end
end
```

If you don't use `||` in setters, then you get `ArgumentError: bad value for range` on empty record.

In your views you can use normal inputs for fields `range_begin` and `range_end`.